# How to use future package with Plumber API

Tags: r, api, future, plumber

I am trying to figure out how to use `future` package with Plumber API. Here is my example:

```
# plumber.R
library(future)

plan("multisession", workers = 2)

simply_wait <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(10)
  line=as.character(Sys.time())
  write(line,file="myfile.txt",append=TRUE)
}


#* Echo the parameter that was sent in
#* @param msg The message to echo back.
#* @get /echo
function(msg="", res){
  
  future_result <- future(simply_wait)
  
  # list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
  res$status <- 202
  
}
```

So I expect to add time stamp to `myfile.txt`, but it is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the endpoint function needs to end with the call to `future` or some future-pipe (e.g., `future(..) %>% promises:then(...)`). (Ref: https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/389 )